# Reset Static fields on change in INI file

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# class library which reads an INI file to obtain the value for a parameter
for e.g. (debug=on)
Now on every call and some times multiple times in one call I have to check this INI and this leads to I/O overhead.
To overcome this I made the parameter in code to be static so at the load time it will check the INI and will store the result.
But now I have to add this condition that reset your IIS or kill your windows form in case you change the INI value.
Note: I dont want to use configuration files (app.config/web.config) as this library is used in various projects (forms/web/services).
So in your opinion what is the best way to Reset Static fields on change in INI file without doing an IIS Reset etc.

Comment: WHY do you have to kill the application or IIS if the INI file is changed?

Comment: Do *not* use GetPrivateProfileXxx(), there's a ton of Windows 3.x appcompat behind it that makes it extraordinarily slow.  Write your own parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason it has to *actually* be static fields? I would suggest having some sort of configuration interface which you can pass around as a dependency to the bits that need it. You can then have three implementations:

- A "fake" with writable properties used for testing
- A "file reading" implementation which reads a file on construction, and is then immutable
- A "file watching" implementation which has the idea of its *current* configuration (and instance of the previous one) and replaces its "current" one when the file changes, via [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). Calls to read the configuration properties simply delegate to the "current" configuration.

This approach will lead to a *much* better testing experience - both for within your class library and potentially for code which *uses* your class library.

If you really, really need a single place that you can always get at a configuration, you could always use the above but have a single static field which refers to the "file watching" implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Look into using a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)